# Setting up MongoDB and Node.js on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am try to set up an environment using Node.js and MongoDB on an installation of ubuntu. I am able to start a mongo database shell by running the `mongo` command. But I am unsure of how to accomplish a couple things.

- How do I set up MongoDB to run persistently, so that I can connect to it?
- How do I connect to a certain MongoDB database from within Node.js once it is up and running?

I have the mongoose package installed, but I am still confused on how to connect to a particular database with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I set up MongoDB to run persistently, so that I can connect to it?

Depends on how you installed the MongoDB.

If you used the whole `apt-get` installation process, it generally installs an `init.d` script and the whole thing just runs with the default settings.

Try a `ps -ef | grep mongod` to look for the `mongod` process.

If you "installed" by downloading the `tar` file, then take a look at using `upstart` or similar process for making it run persistently. You'll want to use config files.

> How do I connect to a certain MongoDB database from within Node.js once it is up and running?

Based on the [Mongoose page](http://mongoosejs.com/), here is the basic connection process:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_database');
```

The standard connection string format is detailed [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Connections). Note that in my experience, not all drivers support all of the connection string features equally well, so do test your configuration.